# What's the exactly the definition of the class in mathematics?

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, terminology

Recently I study the category and I confused with the concept of the class.Sometimes a class is not a set,and sometimes it said a class is.What I know the class is the equivalent class.So what's the class?

Comment: In general, a *class* is the collection of objects satisfying a specific condition expressed by the language of the corresponding theory. A class will be a *set* according to the criteria for set existence available in the theory.

Comment: Usually, if a class $X$ belongs to another class $Y$, then $X$ is a set. See [Class (set theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory)).